# how does a modulus allow a negative number to be encoded

Tags: computer-science, cpu-architecture

if x represents the value to be encoded and y is the number of decimal places to encode a decimal

```
integer_to_big_endian(x * 10**y) % 2**64
```

how would the modulus ensure that negative numbers can also be encoded?

Wouldn't a % of anything bigger than 2**64 give a remainder

So I'm guessing if x * 10 ** y is bigger than 2**64, then you change x * 10 ** y to be big endian so the binary encoding of x * 10 ** y has the most significant byte stored first the modulus will cut off any other bits?

Comment: It's unclear to me where the formula comes from but I believe the modulus is there to emphasize that the size, in bits, of the result is 64. The `integer_to_big_endian` function is the heart of the conversion, `integer_to_big_endian(x)` chooses an appropriate encoding (like 2's complement) and return a new number representing the encoded value. The `* 10**y` is there to create a fixed point format (e.g. 10.23 -> 10230, the last three digits are the decimals).

Comment: oops sorry for the late reply but this library https://github.com/MikeMcl/bignumber.js/